# Enriching Google Search Appliance's indexing with additional URLs

Tags: google-search-appliance

Is there a way to customize how the Google Search Appliance indexes HTML documents? Basically, assuming I have a mapping of keywords to URLs, I'd like the indexer to treat occurrences of the keywords that it finds within HTML documents as if they were links to their respective URLs.

For example if keyword/URL mapping was

```
ABC    -> http://alpha.intra.net/beta/charlie
FOOBAR -> http://barbar.intra.net/foo
XYZ    -> http://xxx.intra.net/yotta/zuul
```

And the document were

```
<html><body>
  Toby was talking about partnering with the folks over in ABC
  on the <a href="http://proj.intra.net/tango">tango</a> project.
  But I think the people over in FOOBAR would be a better fit.
</body></html>
```

The indexer would pull out:

```
http://alpha.intra.net/beta/charlie
http://proj.intra.net/tango
http://barbar.intra.net/foo
```

Alternately, is there a stage before indexing where I could preprocess the HTML to insert such links?

Comment: I'm not sure, but would [configuring GSA to use my keyword/URL mapping as entities](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/current/gsa_doc_set/admin_crawl/advanced_topics.html#discover_and_index_entities) do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible. You can't tell the GSA, "If keyword X, index URL that corresponds to to X-->URL".

However, nothing prevents you from building a proxy sitting between the GSA and the website you index, in order for you to do this transformation in the HTML document that is pushed to the GSA. All you would have to do then would be to configure the GSA to use a proxy server when crawling this URL pattern.

Comment: Would using [a feed](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/feedsguide.html) also be a viable alternative?

Comment: If you already know all the other URLs you would like to ingest, you could ingest those directly through a feed, yes.

Comment: i was thinking as a content feed

Comment: If your URL are accessible using the crawler, consider using a metadata and URL feed. The GSA will handle update and deletions that way.